# possible bug in phantomjs/examples/waitfor.js

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I was testing out https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js and am curious if I've found a bug in the script, am doing something wrong, or possibly don't have the proper settings or flags for running phantomjs.

When running the script, it works great for the first 2-3x I run it. However, after those 2-3x I get the "'waitFor()' Timeout". This happens if I run it 4x or 15x. I can wait 10 mins or a day in between testing it, regardless I get the same issue. I've even switched up urls and change the code around to reflect a different div on the page. I still get the "'waitFor() Timeout". I setup a virtual machine and testing different sites and again after 2-3x attempts, it times out.

I can run other scripts and scrape the same pages and they will work fine, however, with this one script, it only works 2-3x before it continuously times out. Can anyone else confirm this?

Comment: Do you mean 2-3x within the same execution of phantomjs, or 2-3x in general? I've used the example `waitFor` function many, many times successfully, although each execution of phantomjs only uses it once.

Comment: I run phantomjs waitfor.js on the terminal. Let it complete, then run it again.